# What password is the Other Locations window is asking for to connect to my Mac files?

Tags: password, vmware, mac

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on VMWare Fusion Player Ver 12.1.0 that is on my iMac-Pro running Mac OS Big Sur version 11.2.3. I believe I'm to date on all software. I'm trying to access my Mac files from Ubuntu without having to get a Linux programmer's master certificate. So I set up the file sharing in VMWARE while Ubuntu was Shut Down and I see my Mac on the network when I access the Files/Other Locations windows. However, when I click on my computer "Roberts iMac Pro" I am ask for a password (see snapshot). What password? I don't have a login password on the Mac. I tried the network password and the Ubuntu log in password but that doesn't work.
Anyone has a simple answer for me. I'm not even a Linux beginner. I'm using Ubuntu to run a Torrent app.

Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQKT8.png)

Comment: It is the password for roberts-imac-pro.local so ... it will be MAC or Samba(as it also shows a workgroup) related and not Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I tried the only password I use when originally installing Ubuntu and the only password I ever use with the Mac (although now I have remove the need for password everywhere in the Mac. I also tried with no password. No joy. But, that window  is the right place to access my Mac files, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm done with that problem. I had to add an admin password on my Mac, close Ubuntu, close the VM session, restarted the Mac, restarted the VM Ubuntu session , changed the username to the Mac admin username and entered the new password I installed. Ouff, lucky I didn't have to sacrifice a chicken.